# Java-String is never read error!

Tags: java

This is driving me insane! Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] strings) {
    int input;
    String source;
    TextIO.putln("Please enter the shift value (between -25..-1 and 1..25)");
    input=TextIO.getInt();
    while ((input < 1 || input > 25) && (input <-25 || input >-1) && (input != 999 && input !=-999))
    {
        TextIO.putln(input + " is not a valid shift value.");
        TextIO.putln("Please enter the shift value (between -25..-1 and 1..25)");
        input=TextIO.getInt();
    }
    TextIO.putln("Please enter the source text (empty line to quit)");
    //TextIO.putln(source);
    source = TextIO.getln();
    TextIO.putln("Source    :" + source);?");
}

}
```

However, its telling me that 'source' is never read! It's not allowing me to get input! Can anyone see what the problem may be?

Comment: The while condition looks strange, and not what your program asks for. Do you mean "(input >= -25 && input <= -1) || (input >= 1 && input <= 25)" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is correct; the variable `source` is never read. You're assigning a value to it (`source = TextIO.getln();`), but you're never reading that value back out.

To do so, you could do something like:

`TextIO.putln(source);`

You seem to be having trouble reading text from the console with the `TextIO` class. Here's a more standard approach, introduced in Java 5:

```
   String source;
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   source = in.nextLine();
```

What exactly do you wish to do with the variable `source`? As it stands, you're asking the user to enter a string, but you're not doing anything with that string.

Comment: So whats the solution? And how come it works for int 'input'?

Comment: @mohabitar: you **are** reading the value of `input` several times in your program (`input < 1`, etc.). See my edit for how you could write `source` out.

Comment: Ok sorry-I'm new to this, but why do I have to read it? So first I define it by saying String source; Then I want to ask the user for input, so I do. But first I have to read it? Whys that? And also I did what you recommended, but I'm still not able to type in input when I run the program.

Comment: @mohabitar: you must read it **after** you write to it. Otherwise, what's the point? What do you mean by "not able to type in input"? Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: See edit...I put in what I wanna do with it, but its not allowing me to get input.

Comment: @mohabitar: again, what exactly do you mean by "its not allowing me to get input"? Be specific and detailed. Are you getting an error message? A compiler message? What precise behavior are you seeing, that you don't want to?

Comment: No, no error messages. So like when it asks for shift value, I can type in a value in the console. So then I ask for the source (just some random string), but it doesnt let me type anything in the console. I type on my keyboard but it doesnt do anything.

Comment: @mohabitar: I notice you're using a third-party library (TextIO) to read text from the console. You may have to speak with the author to get any further. In the meantime, try a more standard approach: use the `Scanner` class, as I'll write up in an edit.

Comment: @mohabitar: Also remember to type a carriage return after your string.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably ask one of your friends for help instead of posting our homework online. I feel as though this is subjective to cheating. If you are having trouble already, it is only going to get worse. You should be breezing through your freshman year.

Comment: How is this cheating? I'm having trouble with the TextIO method. It's completely general and has nothing to do with this particular problem. Interesting that you found this anyway, were you looking for answers or something?

Comment: I was actually looking up what 'throw new RuntimeException ();' meant, and you came up. Don't get defensive, you will make a good secretary with arguments like that.